# Is it possible to have catchall followed by other parameters in a ASP.NET MVC Route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to create a route that looks something like this:

routes.Add(new Route("{*url}/{action}.do/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())

Is this possible? It seems like the catchall has to be last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx):

> The MVC framework chooses the
>   Controller to use by evaluating the
>   RouteTable rules in the order that
>   they have been registered

I think you *can* register after the catch-all, but it won't ever be hit because the catch-all will be hit first.

Answer (score 1):

The catch-all has to be the last parameter in the route, as it says "match the *entirety* of what remains of the URL."

You could fake it, though, by having just the catchall and using a custom MyRouteHandler instead of the MvcRouteHandler.  Your custom route handler would just manipulate the RouteContext to split the *action* and *id* back out of the URL before passing it to the MvcRouteHandler for processing.